# Copy files from a server via ssh to dropbox.

Tags: ssh, dropbox, scp

I have a user in a linux server (Debian) with ssh access, and have some files on it. I need to copy the files to my Dropbox. but I donot want to copy to my Dropbox in my PC and Laptop, I want to first copy to my Dropbox account directly then sync to my PC and Laptop. Is scp work?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I follow the question. Why not add Dropbox to the server? https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Comment: @wlraider70 make an answer of your comment - it looks excellent.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a better option, a SHELL script that will allow you to upload/download/delete files from the terminal;

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

Tested and works just great.

Comment: Although it's a good option, I wouldn't like to install private stuff from someone else to rely my database backups on my server. The CLI looks like a better choice IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe 
https://couchdrop.io/

The secure, easy to use Cloud scp and http upload server.

```
scp $filename $username@ssh.couchdrop.io:
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why not add Dropbox to the server?
There is a CLI option if you need it.

http://dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Try this:

`scp somefile username@server:/home/username/`

Comment: I have no sudo permission ...

Comment: In fact, you don't need sudo permissions. I just have installed on a linux server and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Why not add Dropbox to the server? Because it may not be a private server where I do not want to download and sync all my local files.

Comment: The question here is not about syncing, it's about pushing. Installing Dropbox implies making all the files public, while the idea I detect here is to use Dropbox to backup file, or as a one-way push.