# Transfer files to cloud by terminal

Tags: 14.04, ftp, cloud

I need a free cloud system, where I can transfer my backup files in range of 1-10 GB, by terminal command from server. Are there such services, what can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277939/copy-files-from-a-server-via-ssh-to-dropbox). There's a SHELL script which lets you write/read to/from your Dropbox account, and also there's a headless Dropbox installation which lets you access your account via the command line. To install it, issue these commands:

32-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

64-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.